# App not being downloaded to simulator (ios)

Tags: nativescript

When I run `tns run ios`, the app is not being downloaded to the simulator.

But when I do `tns deploy ios` - then it does work.

Any suggestions?

I did a `tns build ios` and verified the app was being built successfully.

When I do `tns run ios` I do get the `watching` message - but the app hasn't even downloaded.

I'm using 5.0

Comment: Start your Simulator, try running `tns devices` and see if your iOS simulator is being listed.

Comment: Yes it is. As I wrote - `tns deploy ios` works.